# Git remote command returns fatal: Invalid refspec +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/:origin/*

Tags: git, github

I accidentally modified my git config file and now hitting `git remote --v` in the terminal it returns: `fatal: Invalid refspec '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/:origin/*'`,

What could be wrong in my config file, this is how it looks:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@github.com/myuserame/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/:origin/*
```

Any idea will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Use an editor, undo all changes that you made to `config` file

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can fix it with a:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

(removing the `:` in `:origin`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Where should I find related information regarding this command line?

Comment: @CloudCho 7 years after having written this answer, I believe the documentation is [Git Internals - The Refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete the [remote "origin"] section from your config file and reinitialize the remote settings in the CLI as if you had not yet done it for the repository in the first place.